# How to run only smoke test cases suite in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, smoke-testing

I want to run smoke tests independently from builds and releases in Azure Pipelines. I have ReactJS app and WebdriverIO framework for tests. Maybe I can use any script to run only particular tests (smoke)?